# easier way to find aws managed policies ARNs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I tend to go to the console to find ARNs for managed policies. I was wondering if there is an easy way to locate all of those and grab the ARNs since they don't rely on your account number or anything.

I understand I can construct them by adding the policy name at the end here: arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/PolicyName But some of the policies could be for service role policies so link changes then and case sensitivity is another concern.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean here? Is this: https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/iam/list-policies.html what you're looking for?